# How to represent a date of birth in Dart?

Tags: dart

Let's say I want to represent a person with their name and date of birth.  I could write this in Dart:

```
class Person {

  String name;
  DateTime dateOfBirth;

}
```

The problem is that DateTime has a timezone offset so if I want to sort people by age then I need to implement my own Comparator callback function which only looks at the year, month and day properties of dateOfBirth.

An alternative is to add a class invariant to Person to ensure that the dateOfBirth is always in UTC, then my sort comparator becomes much simpler: `(p1, p2) => p1.dateOfBirth.compareTo(p2.dateOfBirth)`

Both these approaches feel wrong because I don't care about the timezone component - what I really want is a class which just represents (year, month, day) in the Gregorian calendar.  I've found [this class](https://pub.dev/packages/date_calendar), but it's not very popular.  Is there some standard Dart class that I can use?  Or do most Dart programmers just use DateTime to represent such a concept?

Comment: If you want built in dart class then there is none. It is better just to always initialize date using DateTime.utc() constructor. and don't use time fields.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure only year/month/day are included when saving the DoB.

```
date = getDobFromUser();
dob = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day);
```

If you need more granularity than that, you should include the time they were born and probably store it as milliseconds since the Unix epoch for easy sorting.

Comment: He already knows this solution. He is asking for a standard class that doesn't contain time fields.